# Images and text inside a button

Tags: html, css

So I'm having a little problem with these 3 buttons. What I want is the text in the bottom of the image aligned to the center of the button and of course the image above centered too.

What it looks now:

[image]

Code:

```
    <div id="box">

        <button onclick="Edit();"><img src="images/edit.png" alt="Editar Conteúdo" /><span>Editar Conteúdo</span></button>

        <button onclick="Users();"><img src="images/users.png" alt="Utilizadores" /><span>Gerir Utilizadores</span></button>

        <button onclick="Logout();"><img src="images/logout.png" alt="Logout" /><span>Logout</span></button>

    </div>
```

CSS:

```
#box {
max-width:699px;
width:100%;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}

button{
font-family:Consolas, sans-serif;
background-color:white;
border:3px solid #EBEBEB;
border-radius:5px;
max-width:230px;
height:auto;
min-height:150px;
width:100%;
transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
padding: 1px 6px 1px 6px;
}

button:hover {
transform: scale(1.09);
}

button > * {  
vertical-align: middle;  
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't a `<br />` after each image do the trick?

Comment: Why did not I remember that? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3):

Forcing a line break between the image and span should do the trick. Ex:

```
<img src="images/edit.png" alt="Editar Conteúdo" /><br /><span>
```